# NSLock.lock() executed while lock already held?

Tags: swift, closures, alamofire, nslock

I'm reviewing some Alamofire [sample](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#adapting-and-retrying-requests) Retrier code:

```
   func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {
        lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }

        if let response = request.task.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
            requestsToRetry.append(completion)

            if !isRefreshing {
                refreshTokens { [weak self] succeeded, accessToken, refreshToken in
                    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                    strongSelf.lock.lock() ; defer { strongSelf.lock.unlock() }

                    ...
                }
            }
        } else {
            completion(false, 0.0)
        }
    }
```

I don't follow how you can have `lock.lock()` on the first line of the function and then also have that same line `strongSelf.lock.lock()` within the closure passed to `refreshTokens`.

If the first lock is not released until the end of the `should` method when the `defer` unlock is executed then how does the the second `strongSelf.lock.lock()` successfully execute while the first lock is held?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trailing closure of `refreshTokens`, where this second call to `lock()`/`unlock()` is called, runs asynchronously. This is because the closure is `@escaping` and is called from within a `responseJSON` inside the `refreshTokens` routine. So the `should` method will have performed its deferred `unlock` by the time the closure of `refreshTokens` is actually called.

Having said that, this isn't the most elegant code that I've seen, where the utility of the lock is unclear and the risk of deadlocking is so dependent upon the implementation details of other routines. It looks like it's OK here, but I don't blame you for raising an eyebrow at it.